# Unwanted items on a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a problem while using a subset of a `data.frame` in R.

The subset gets created and displayed correctly, but when I try to plot it using `qplot()`, the rows which were not selected by the `subset()` also get shown along one axis.

The actual file I am reading in is a web server log, but I have created a small example to illustrate my problem:

This is the `ITEMSSOLD.CSV` file I read in:

```
CUST,DT,ITEM,PRICE
BigJoe,10/13/2010,Pickup Truck,20000
TightWad,10/13/2010,USB Drive,12
Jane,10/13/2010,Smart Car,30000
Scrooge,10/13/2010,Gumdrops,1
GeekyMan,10/13/2010,Smart Car,30000
```

I read this into a data frame as follows:

```
sales_df <- read.table("C:/R_Expt/ItemsSold.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

I then did a subset to get the high-ticket items as follows:

```
big_sales_df <- subset(sales_df, PRICE>100)

big_sales_df

big_sales_df
      CUST         DT         ITEM PRICE
1   BigJoe 10/13/2010 Pickup Truck 20000
3     Jane 10/13/2010    Smart Car 30000
5 GeekyMan 10/13/2010    Smart Car 30000
```

So that looks OK.

When I try to plot it via `qplot` as follows:

```
qplot(nrow, ITEM, data = ddply(big_sales_df, .(ITEM), "nrow"))
```

the resulting plot shows **all** the ITEMS on the Y axis, instead of only Pickup Truck and 
Smart Car.

The `ddply()` alone produces the following output:

```
ddply(big_sales_df, .(ITEM), "nrow")
          ITEM nrow
1 Pickup Truck    1
2    Smart Car    2
```

Since the example has a small number of ITEMs, the plot is still readable, but in real life, I am trying to plot the names of slow web pages and unfortunately, `qplot()` tries to put the names of all webpages along the Y axis and it becomes a black blur.

I tried `sqldf()` also:

```
qplot(NSOLD, ITEM, data = sqldf('select ITEM, count(*) as NSOLD from big_sales_df group by ITEM order by count(*) desc'))
```

but this produces the same plot.

What I understood is that `subset()` is somehow carrying the full parent information inside, instead of just the matched rows.

Is there any way of telling `subset()`that it should only keep the relevant information?

Or any other way of getting around `subset()` carrying along the empty members?

I know that a brute force method might be to write the result of the `subset()` into another CSV file and then read it back in a `data.frame`, but I am sure there is an easier way.

Many thanks to all your R gurus out there!

Atish

Answer (score 1):

When you subset your data the factors that existed in the original data set persist. Take the diamonds data set for example. You have 5 different cuts.

```
unique(diamonds$cut) ## Ideal, Premium, Good, Very Good, Fair
```

If we subset diamonds, we get:

```
str(subset(diamonds, cut == "Ideal")) ## Look at structure
```

In str(), we see that cut maintains the factors that it had originally.

```
$ cut    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Fair","Good",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
```

Even though we've removed all the other categories of cut, the factoring persists.

You can remove the extra factors by refactoring the column with it's own unique subsetted factors.

```
x$cut <- factor(x$cut, labels=unique(x$cut))
```

Now looking more specifically at your example:

```
test <- ddply(big_sales_df, .(ITEM), "nrow")
test$ITEM <- factor(test$ITEM, labels=unique(test$ITEM))
```

Now, try your plot again.

Comment: I posted another answer that does the same thing, but in situ in the plot. IN qplot() replace ITEM with factor(ITEM)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the factor levels that were dropped from your subset.

```
big_sales_df$ITEM <- factor(big_sales_df$ITEM)
big_sales_df$CUST <- factor(big_sales_df$CUST)
```

OR change how you read in the data:

```
sales_df <- read.csv("ItemsSold.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can cheat by factoring item:

```
qplot(nrow, factor(ITEM), data = ddply(big_sales_df, .(ITEM), "nrow")
```

Comment: Oops, I meant to add that there was a slight typo in your answer - it should be:qplot(nrow, factor(ITEM), data = ddply(big_sales_df, .(ITEM), "nrow"))

Comment: And I like this solution better as it gives me more control, in case I want to plot by several dimensions.

Comment: @Atish: if you like this solution, you should make it the accepted answer.